# How to export the objects in an array to individual objects in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb

I'm new to coding and Node.js, so apologies if this has been asked or is stupid. I'm trying to import data from an api into my mongodb database.  I'm currently getting all of the data at once and using object mapping to sort through it.  The problem I have is some items are objects, some are strings and some are arrays.  I'm having an issue with the arrays.  I would like to de-structure them so to say, so that I can import each item individually if this makes sense.

Here's my current sloppy code.

```
const PropertyRate = Object.values(Property).map((val) => {
  return {
    UnitCode: val.UnitCode,
    UnitName: val.UnitInfo.UnitName.UnitShortName,

    Rates: val.UnitInfo.RateRanges.RateRange.map((val) => {
      return {
        Start: val.Start,
        End: val.End,
        RateType: val.RateType,
        MinRate: val.MinRate,
        MaxRate: val.MaxRate,
        RateTimeUnit: val.RateTimeUnit,
        MinRent: val.MinRent,
        MaxRent: val.MaxRent,
        MinFees: val.MinFees,
        MaxFees: val.MaxFees,
        MinTax: val.MinTax,
        MaxTax: val.MaxTax,
        SeasonName: val.SeasonName,
        StayRequirement: val.StayRequirement,
      }
    }),
  }
})
```

In my DB it shows up like this.

```
_id: 64125a19b37358a4ff03132d
UnitCode: "1886-76875"
UnitName: "Test Property"
Rates: Array
0:Object
1:Object
2:Object
3:Object
4:Object
__v: 0
```

Is there a way to take this information and convert it so that each Rate object is inserted as an individual document?  Is it even worth doing this?  I just figured it would be easier to query for a rate that's current for a given date for a specific property.  Each Unit has about 35-50 Rate objects and I'm storing them in a separate collection because there's about 500,000 lines of information for only 130 units.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly you want to [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) over `Object.values(Property)` and then `map()` over `UnitInfo.RateRanges.RateRange` and create an object with the relevant `UnitCode` and `UnitName` for each rate.

```
const PropertyRate = Object.values(Property).flatMap((property) => {
  return property.UnitInfo.RateRanges.RateRange.map((rate) => {
    return {
      UnitCode: property.UnitCode,
      UnitName: property.UnitInfo.UnitName.UnitShortName,
      Rate: {
        Start: rate.Start,
        End: rate.End,
        RateType: rate.RateType,
        MinRate: rate.MinRate,
        MaxRate: rate.MaxRate,
        RateTimeUnit: rate.RateTimeUnit,
        MinRent: rate.MinRent,
        MaxRent: rate.MaxRent,
        MinFees: rate.MinFees,
        MaxFees: rate.MaxFees,
        MinTax: rate.MinTax,
        MaxTax: rate.MaxTax,
        SeasonName: rate.SeasonName,
        StayRequirement: rate.StayRequirement,
      },
    };
  });
});
```

When approaching something like this it can help to approach it in a procedural way which can end up describing quite clearly what you are after. Here using `for...of` loops.

```
const PropertyRates = [];

for (const property of Object.values(Property)) {
  for (const rate of property.UnitInfo.RateRanges.RateRange) {
    const propertyRate = {
      UnitCode: property.UnitCode,
      UnitName: property.UnitInfo.UnitName.UnitShortName,
      Rate: {
        Start: rate.Start,
        End: rate.End,
        RateType: rate.RateType,
        MinRate: rate.MinRate,
        MaxRate: rate.MaxRate,
        RateTimeUnit: rate.RateTimeUnit,
        MinRent: rate.MinRent,
        MaxRent: rate.MaxRent,
        MinFees: rate.MinFees,
        MaxFees: rate.MaxFees,
        MinTax: rate.MinTax,
        MaxTax: rate.MaxTax,
        SeasonName: rate.SeasonName,
        StayRequirement: rate.StayRequirement,
      },
    };

    PropertyRates.push(propertyRate);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!  This solved my issue perfectly on the first try.  I spent a couple of days trying different things to get this to work.  You are a genius.